# Error Installing Python Bcrypt using pip install bcrypt in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, bcrypt

Please help me figure our why am I unable to install bcrypt in my system running ubuntu 14.04

**Error :**

```
somehostname@somehost:~$ pip install bcyrpt
Collecting bcyrpt

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bcyrpt (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for bcyrpt

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

I think the error is not because of the warnings, because that is not what the line **Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bcyrpt (from versions: )** says.

Please tell me what is the issue and why is this problem occurring? And how to solve this problem?

Things I have tried already:

1. `pip install --pre bcrypt`
2. `pip install bcrypt==2.0.0`

**NOTE:** I have already installed all the dependencies as required and mentioned in the github repo like libffi-dev, libssl-dev, etc. Also I am running my instance in an AWS t2.micro instance with 1 GB Ram running ubuntu 14.04. Just for additional info.

Comment: try `sudo pip install -U cryptography pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1 urllib3[secure]`

Comment: @user2683246 Can you explain the reason. Actually I have already done pyopenssl, ndg-httpsclient and also note i am using Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually a pretty simple mistake. According to the console log you posted, you're spelling `bcrypt` wrong. You probably need to run it as sudo as well.

```
sudo pip install bcrypt
```

Comment: Really typos take your time away sometimes. Thanks. Its solved now. Successfully installed.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!